# Best way to implement union type container

Tags: rust

I have a bunch of types:

```
struct A { cool_thing: &'static str }
struct B {}
struct C {}
struct D {}
```

I also have a way of identifying the types, e.g.

```
trait Name {
    fn name(&self) -> &'static str;
}

impl Name for A {
    fn name(&self) -> &'static str { return "A"; }
}
// etc.
```

Given the above, what is the best way to implement a container for these types? For instance, I want something like this:

```
struct Container {
    item: Box<Name>,
}

impl Container {
    fn new(item: Box<Name>) -> Container {
        return Container { item: item };
    }

    fn get_item(&self) -> &Name {
        return self.item.as_ref();
    }
}
```

Later, I'd like to use this container:

```
let a = A { cool_thing: "Yah!" };
let container = Container::new(Box::new(a));
let thing = container.get_item();
if thing.name == "A" {
    // How to access cool_thing here?
}
```

How can this be accomplished?

I'd like `Container` to be able to store objects without depending on them explicitly. This is to avoid possible circular dependencies where an object might want to consume a `Container` as well as populate it with some local type (specifically I'm trying to implement the "entity" of an [entity-component-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system). The dependency issue makes using something like an enum inappropriate.

Comment: Since you're implementing an ECS, have you watched [Catherine West's closing keynote from Rustconf this year](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKLntZcp27M)? It's not super in-depth, but well worth 45 minutes in my opinion.

Comment: Explicit returns at the end of the block are considered unidiomatic Rust. Just let the last expression be the return value (`fn name(&self) -> &'static str { "A" }`; `fn new(item: Box<Name>) -> Container { Container { item } }`, etc.). You can also avoid repeating yourself when constructing `Container` by only saying `item` once.

Comment: You may find https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-do-c-like-inheritance/20545 interesting